# Preg_replace dynamic content?

Tags: php, regex, database, preg-replace

I am using preg_replace to create a snippet of searched content on my site and highlight the term that was searched (like google). It works when I use a static variable on my page but when I retrieve the data from the database it doesn't. The code is as follows:

```
foreach ($searchcontent ->result() as $row)
{
$text = $row->content;
$keyword = 'investment'; 
$size = 165; 

$snippet = preg_replace(
    '/^.*?\s(.{0,'.$size.'})(\b'.$keyword.'\b)(.{0,'.$size.'})\s.*?$/',
    '...$1<strong>$2</strong>$3...',
    $text
);
echo $snippet;

  }
```

If I change the $text variable for some static content like: 
`"We are happy to consultant on your investments"` it works. But when I get the data from the db it doesn't.

Sample of text from database (contains html, may be the issue),

```
<h2>Investments<h2>
<hr />
<p>We are happy to consult on your investments</p>
```

How would one go about stripping the string of html tags?? and getting the preg_replace working????

Comment: Of course this is the issue. Does the db return every single time the same html ? Or could it vary?

Comment: more or less the same format, but may vary

Comment: I think a `str_replace()` would be enough, as long as you're dealing with plain html. Anyway, the `regex` expression mentioned seems overcomplicated comparing to it's subject.

Comment: Then regex is not your friend in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works : http://codepad.org/Ve1dhj8q

However, it would be better if you paste a real database result, since the problem might be there.

**Edit**

This is what you want. You can use `preg_match()` to capture the contents before ( `$matches[1]` ) and after ( `$matches[2]` ), and don't forget to check if there was any match found ( using `count()` ). Only thing left is to add the previous posted code in order to highlight the words. `$limit` is the offset.

```
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent consectetur tempor egestas. Nam arcu augue, bibendum sed pulvinar at, posuere ut massa. Duis tristique suscipit rutrum. Curabitur eu est sed sem consequat consequat ut sed erat. Aliquam ac eros est. Nulla posuere dolor eu arcu tempus suscipit auctor velit condimentum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas sollicitudin diam ut neque laoreet vitae placerat tortor commodo. Aliquam vehicula aliquet arcu non molestie. Sed adipiscing faucibus faucibus. In eget velit non elit ullamcorper consequat.';

$limit = 50;
$keyword = 'tempus';


preg_match('/(.{0,'.$limit.'})'.$keyword.'(.{0,'.$limit.'})/', $text, $matches);

echo var_dump($matches);
```

**Example output**

```
array(3)
{
  [0]=> string(106) " Aliquam ac eros est. Nulla posuere dolor eu arcu tempus suscipit auctor velit condimentum. Class aptent t"

  [1]=> string(50) " Aliquam ac eros est. Nulla posuere dolor eu arcu "

  [2]=> string(50) " suscipit auctor velit condimentum. Class aptent t"
}
```

**Bonus**

If you for design / markup purposes need to limit the phrase to, lets say 100 words (example, in case your div container can only take a certain amount of characters in order to keep the layout balance), you can do this :

```
$limit = 0;
$total = 100;
$keyword = 'yumm';

$limit = (int) ($total - strlen($keyword)) / 2);
```

Comment: Not in that context, no. You can use it though, it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Using the code you have pasted, how can I limit the words echoed around the highlighted keyword?? This is important as the text is long..

Comment: Hi Yoda thanks for that, trying to run the code in codepad and get an error. what does the $matches variable do???

Comment: Codepad `preg_match` is limited for some reason, try it locally or in a webserver, it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use PHP's [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

```
$text = strip_tags($row->content);
```

Comment: Hi Clive, I have stripped the text of tags, but the preg_replace still doesn't run on the content from the database. Any ideas???